# How can I satisfy my woes with R's `:` operator?

Tags: r, operators, sequence

R's `:` operator has some well-known gotchas:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3)
set.zero = function(n) a[1:n] <<- 0
set.zero(0)
# `a` is now c(0, 2, 3)
```

I could just write a function that solves this by making `1:0` give an empty
vector, but I'd prefer it if there were a reasonably terse `base` or CRAN
package that provided such a function (ideally replacing `:` if that's not too
dangerous). I've tried to search for one but can't find it.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.zero = function(n) a[seq_len(n)] <<- 0
```

Note that `seq(1, length = n)` works as well.

Comment: Nice. Though it requires arithmetic to generalize to `a:b`.

Comment: @Owen Arithmetic!? The horror! The horror! ;)

Comment: @Owen, Have added some info on that.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen - <<- sets a variable globally (<- just sets it locally); in this case, I'm not sure there's any need for it thought.

Comment: @Brandon @ChrisW It is necessary here because `a` is nonlocal to the function `set.zero`